# How to set width after using row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

In this code when I am not using row then proceed button is not expanding but when I am using Row for adding one more widget then that is expanding.

This is my code.

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'assets/assets_allocation_image.png',
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Know your\nASSET ALLOCATION",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: tSize18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10, right: 10, top: 5, bottom: 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: orangeColor,
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: orangeColor, width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(3),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(                                                   // here
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Proceed',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: tSize12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: whiteColor),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 3,),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 18,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

This is my ui
[image]

I want UI like this

[image]

### How to possible without wrapping in container and without giving width Becouse if I will give fix width then if user changed text size from mobile device then it will give me overflow error.
so how to  fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `mainAxisSize` and row will not expand anymore

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Container` tries to expand to the **available space**. Since you are using `Column` as it's parent, there are no restrictions on width of the `Container`. Hence it expands to its **full width**.

One way you can achieve is by replacing the `Container` with `DecoratedBox` which has no size constraints and tries to fit to the width and height of its child widget. Use proper padding around the `Text` widget. That would be sufficient to achieve the above.

Also add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `Row` widget.

Example code is as below. Please look at the code comment as well for the changes

```
Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Know your\nASSET ALLOCATION",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: tSize18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
              child: DecoratedBox( // change Container to DecoratedBox
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: orangeColor,
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: orangeColor, width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(3),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:24,vertical:16),//here change the value as per your requirement
                   child :Row(                                                   
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Proceed',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: tSize12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: whiteColor),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 3,),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 18,
                    )
                  ],
                 ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```